# Firefox OS simulator: Hold file in device-storage:apps

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os

I want to use `device-storage:apps` for holding files
([API Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/Device_Storage_API)).

For example, system application (*certified*):

I add permissions for manifest:

```
"device-storage:apps":{ "access": "readwrite" },
"webapps-manage":{ }
```

In code of system application (*certified*), I use:

```
var storage_apps = navigator.getDeviceStorage("apps");
var file   = new Blob(["This is a text file."], {type: "text/plain"});
var request = storage_apps.addNamed(file, "my-file.txt");
```

After I build Gaia and get profile, and run this profile on Simulator, version 2.2.

But I got **security error.**

Is this operation is possible for Firefox OS?

Comment: I got answer from Mozilla's developer: device-storage:apps is read-only, there's no write permission to it. The
only areas where you can write files are pictures, videos, music and sdcard.